# How to hide imported Python libraries?

Tags: 12.04, python, libraries

I am a beginning coder in Python. This may sound misplaced, but wait up a second. My program depends on a couple of libraries that I have allowed it to use via `import`. These libraries are now showing up in my home directory as "PS Documents". Is there a way to hide them without preventing my Python script from accessing them?

Comment: Could you add (a link to) the code?

Comment: I used `import time` and `import random`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like you used the shell instead of Python to run your Python program.

Make sure the first line of your Python  program is something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

See [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for more about this.

If your Python program is run by the shell the shell calls [import](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/import.1.html) (part of ImageMagick) for each of your import statements. This program waits for you to click any window and then takes a screenshot of that window and saves it under the name gives as argument, by default as PostScript file.

For example

```
import sys
```

will wait for you to click on a window and save a screenshot of that window in a PostScript file named `sys` in the current directory.

You can just delete those PostScript files.

Comment: Brilliant, would never have thought of that :)

Comment: I use `python /path/to/file` to run my scripts.

Comment: @It'sWillem That is odd; it should then run correctly without the shebang. Somehow what Florian describes must be the case though. Are you sure you didn't accidentally run without?

Comment: Fascinating. That makes no sense

Comment: @It's Willem: Maybe you did it by accident, or some program did. In any case Python neither creates nor needs those PostScript files so you can just delete them.